# Getting CardView with id in Java

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I am currently working on an android studio project and I need to set the visibility of a cardview to gone in my layout.
I am currently able to get the webview which is nestedinside the cardview in java as such.

```
WebView webViewCO2;
webViewCO2 = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webviewCO2);
```

Is there a way for me to do the same thing to get the Cardview?

Comment: Well.... Do the same with the cardview.... Give it an ID and then do just what you did there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give CardView an id, say, cv_id;
Do,

```
CardView cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cv_id);
```

afterthis, where-ever you need to set it's visiblity to gone, do,

```
cardView.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
```